# Cannot find the bug in the CopyRow code from Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy, cell, google-sheets-macros

I'm looking for a code to copy 4 cells for the row that I've selected the cell from one sheet from another sheet of the same spreadsheet, on the last row that is written. The code is this:

```
function CopiarFila() {

//declaration of sheets

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID");

var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("FORD 2019");

var sheetTo = ss.getSheetByName("FORD 2019-F");

//declaration of variables

var row = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();

var range1 = sheet.getRange("B"+row+":B"+row).getValues();
var range2 = sheet.getRange("C"+row+":C"+row).getValues();
var range3 = sheet.getRange("F"+row+":F"+row).getValues();
var range4 = sheet.getRange("I"+row+":I"+row).getValues();


//declaration of the last row from the new sheet

var ultimaFila = sheetTo.getLastRow();

//adding a row after the last one

sheetTo.insertRowsAfter(ultimaFila, 1); 

//copying values to the last row

sheetTo.getRange("B"+ultimaFila+":B"+ultimaFila).setValues(range1);
sheetTo.getRange("D"+ultimaFila+":D"+ultimaFila).setValues(range2);
sheetTo.getRange("C"+ultimaFila+":C"+ultimaFila).setValues(range3);
sheetTo.getRange("H"+ultimaFila+":H"+ultimaFila).setValues(range4);`



}
```

As I see when running the code, the row is created so the problem isn't from the commands: Sheet, SheetTo and ultimaFila. Am I using properly the command '.getValues('?

I'm stuck and I cannot find a way to fix it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail information of your issue? And can I ask you about ``the last row`` you are thinking? Because in your script, the last row of the sheet ``FORD 2019-F`` is overwritten. If this is the result you want, it's no problem.

Answer (score 0):

IF you don't mind the blank columns, there is an easier way to do this,

```
var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("FORD 2019");
var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("FORD 2019-F");

ss1.getRange("B:B").copyTo(ss2.getRange("B:B"));
ss1.getRange("C:C").copyTo(ss2.getRange("D:D"));
ss1.getRange("F:F").copyTo(ss2.getRange("C:C"));
ss1.getRange("I:I").copyTo(ss2.getRange("H:H"));
```

Comment: Hi, the problem here is that I need to copy 4 of the cells from the row that I've selected, not the whole row.